# Trying to find the URI location on server

Tags: biztalk

I am new to BizTalk and tying to figure out where can I find the URI location of a server.

As you see below, the URI is SQL://CORDINASQL/FinanceApp

Where can I find it and how?

[image: Biztalk]

[image: Configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL://CORDINASQL/FinanceApp.. is the URI.

In this case it is a SQL Server URI where the SQL Server name is CORDINASQL and the Database is FinanceApp...

You can find the details by clicking on the Configure button and then on the ... next to Connection String.

[image: SQL Transport Properties]

P.S. If you are considering making changes to this port you might consider using the WCF-SQL adapter rather than this deprecated SQL adapter.

**UPDATE:**

CORDINASQL is an alias for the SQL server.

Check the file c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and see if they have put an entry in there for CORDINASQL to point to a IP address. Either that or your network team has done something in the your network so that name resolves to the correct IP address

Comment: Thank you, I just saw the Configure option and it shows the image which I have updated in my original post. The thing which I got to know is that, in the original server a mapping is done such that CORDINASQL can be used instead of original server name (helps avoiding duplication for other suppliers). I am not sure how do we do that or any software?

Comment: Check the file c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts  and see if they have put an entry in there for CORDINASQL to point to a IP address.  Either that or your network team has done something in the your network so that name resolves to the correct IP address.

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted. Thanks a lot again :)